# Is it possible to mine my own txs with no fees?

Tags: blockchain, mining, gas-price, fees

It seems like minimum tx fee is around .001$ in Ethereum (maybe a little bit less) but I was wondering about the possibility of performing zero fee transactions, mining them by myself. Obviously, sending txs with gasPrice = 0 is useless because miners are not going to give them any priority, but ...

- What if I change that priority in my own node?
- Can I specify somehow on geth to mine with priority my own zero fee
  transactions?
- Is it possible to send transactions with gasPrice = 0?

Comment: Everything you mention is certainly possible, but not a standard feature in nodes. It would be pretty easy to mod one of the clients to do this, if you really wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A miner does not mine one transaction in isolation. A miner mines a block, which has transactions. If you have a miner, it is competing with the other miners in mining the next block. If your miner is powerful enough, it may mine a block from time to time. In these rare occasions, you could accept your own cheap transactions.

However, I would not bother because the expense of getting a powerful miner goes above the cost of a regularly priced transaction. I think.

If, now, you have created your own Ethereum network with a few nodes, once again it does not matter because your node is mining many of the blocks and so you have enough to pay for the gas of all the transactions you want.